# PhoneGap orientation change crash even with Manifest changes

Tags: android, cordova

I've seen lots of references or similar questions, but all of them teaches me to do this:
Add "android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale" into the

But it's done and on orientation change, the app crashes. I tried to follow every single tip and it doesn't work.

This is my manifest file:

```
   <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="com.guia.peixe"
        android:versionCode="1"
        android:versionName="1.0" >

        <uses-sdk
            android:minSdkVersion="8"
            android:targetSdkVersion="15" />
        <supports-screens 
        android:largeScreens="true" 
        android:normalScreens="true" 
        android:smallScreens="true" 
        android:resizeable="true" 
        android:anyDensity="true" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" /> 
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BROADCAST_STICKY" />
        <application
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
            <activity
                android:name=".MainActivity"
                android:label="@string/title_activity_main" 
                android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>
        </application>

    </manifest>
```

This is the final version of the code, when it's done, I get an error:

Description Resource    Path    Location    Type error: Error: String types not allowed (at 'configChanges' with value 'orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale'). AndroidManifest.xml    /G‌​uia do Peixe    line 34 Android AAPT Problem

But the example on Cordova's documentation points out to this, and no change I make into the string correct the error.

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because your XML is not valid. It should be:

```
<activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/title_activity_main"
    android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale">
```

Note, you have the > in the wrong position.

Comment: OP should take a look at the code he posted, even the SO formatting shows this